# OCR doesn't recognize phone numbers with the sign (-)

Tags: python, ocr

I'm trying to extract phone number from the following image (after resize:)
[image]
my code :

```
from PIL import Image
from pyocr import pyocr
import pyocr.builders
import cStringIO
import os
os.putenv("TESSDATA_PREFIX", "/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/")
tools = pyocr.get_available_tools()
tool = tools[0]
langs = tool.get_available_languages()
lang = langs[0]
file = "test.png"
txt = tool.image_to_string(Image.open(file),
                           lang=lang,
                            builder=pyocr.builders.TextBuilder())
print txt
```

it returns Empty string.
When there is no (-) in the phone number, it returns it correctly.
What should I do ? 
Thanks !

Comment: Will the "-" always be at the same place? If that's the case you could split the image a couple times to remove the "-" and then concatenate the results of running OCR on each separate image.

Comment: Can you provide a code example ?

Comment: Provided some code - check it out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, when I ran your code with tesseract and the image you provided it perfectly returned the text (dashes and spaces included). At that point you could obviously just use `txt = txt.replace("-", "").replace(" ", "")` to get rid of the dashes and whitespace.

Buuuuuut I know that OCR (even with us both using tesseract) is going to be different across platforms, so I've included an example of my comment suggestion.

## First we split the images at the dashes, then we read each split image, then we concatenate:

```
# I changed your imports a bit
from PIL import Image
from pyocr import pyocr
from pyocr import builders
import cStringIO
import os

# set up all your OCR stuff
os.putenv("TESSDATA_PREFIX", "/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/")
tools = pyocr.get_available_tools()
tool = tools[0]
langs = tool.get_available_languages()
lang = "eng" #set language to english to simplify things

# definte a function to return the text of a given image
def doOCR( fName ):
    txt = tool.image_to_string(Image.open(fName), lang=lang, builder=builders.TextBuilder())
    return txt

# define the path of the image we are going to read
path = "test.png"

# get the image dimensions
im = Image.open(path)
width, height = im.size

# define the points we want to split the image at
# these are the points where the dashes are
split_points = [119, 158]

# define the file names for the image parts
split_names = ["split-1.png", "split-2.png", "split-3.png"]

# define a function to crop the image and remove the dashes
def doCrop(imagePath, cropPath, x, y, x2, y2):
    im = Image.open(imagePath)
    box = (x, y, x2, y2)
    region = im.crop(box) # extract the box region
    region.save(cropPath) # save it as a separate image

# in the image you provided each "-" is ~10 pixels long
lenpix = 10

# crop the image at the split points
doCrop(path, split_names[0], 0, 0, split_points[0], height) # get the first section
doCrop(path, split_names[1], split_points[0] + lenpix, 0, split_points[1], height) # get the middle section
doCrop(path, split_names[2], split_points[1] + lenpix, 0, width, height) # get the final section

# define a variable for our final value
finalValue = ""

# finally iterate through split files
# and add the OCR results from each split together
for f in split_names:
    finalValue += doOCR(f) # concatenate the ocr value with the final
    os.remove(f) # remove the split file now that we've used it

# display the final value
print finalValue
```

Worked like a charm for me:
[image]

Hope this helped!

Comment: +1 for the detailed answer ! 
I will try it now and I just want to point out that I haven't done any training to my OCR , Have you ?

Comment: @Sekai Nope didn't even have tesseract installed until I realized I needed it to run your code. Maybe a fresh install for you would help?